# get the id of the clicked instance in a django panel

Tags: django

I created two buttons and I am going to describe you the creation process and the functionality and finally I will ask my question.

I have a django class of heroes.
One button makes all heroes mortal, and one which makes all immortal. Since it affects all heroes irrespective of the selection, this needs to be a separate button, not an action dropdown.

First, we will change the template on the HeroAdmin so we can add two buttons:

```
@admin.register(Hero)
class HeroAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
change_list_template = "entities/heroes_changelist.html"
```

Then we will override the get_urls, and add the set_immortal and set_mortal methods on the model admin. They will serve as the two view methods:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()
    my_urls = [
        path('immortal/', self.set_immortal),
        path('mortal/', self.set_mortal),
    ]
    return my_urls + urls

def set_immortal(self, request):
    self.model.objects.all().update(is_immortal=True)
    self.message_user(request, "All heroes are now immortal")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("../")

def set_mortal(self, request):
    self.model.objects.all().update(is_immortal=False)
    self.message_user(request, "All heroes are now mortal")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

Finally, we create the entities/heroes_changelist.html template by extending the admin/change_list.html:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
{% block object-tools %}
   <div>
    <form action="immortal/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit">Make Immortal</button>
    </form>
    <form action="mortal/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit">Make Mortal</button>
    </form>
</div>
<br />
{{ block.super }}
```

{% endblock %}

And after using the make_mortal action, the Heroes are all mortal and you see this message:

[image]

My Question is: How can I do if I only want to make mortal one specific heroe, the only one who I clicked with the mouse on the small box, at left of the name of the heroe.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils.translation import ngettext

@admin.register(Hero)
class HeroAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
    change_list_template = "entities/heroes_changelist.html"
    actions = ['make_mortal', 'make_immortal']

    def make_mortal(self, request, queryset):
        updated = queryset.update(is_immortal=False)
        self.message_user(request, ngettext(
            '%d person was successfully marked mortal.',
            '%d person were successfully marked mortal.',
            updated,
        ) % updated, messages.SUCCESS)
    

    def make_immortal(self, request, queryset):
        updated = queryset.update(is_immortal=True)
        self.message_user(request, ngettext(
            '%d person was successfully marked immortal.',
            '%d person were successfully marked immortal.',
            updated,
        ) % updated, messages.SUCCESS)
```

Then you will have options like this:

[image]

Comment: but I need to have the two original buttons

Comment: I am afraid it's going to need too much customization in template code, which first not going to be a clean code and second very much time-consuming. The reason why, because your functions "set_immortal" and "set_mortal", will not know which item has been selected, so you have to check how you can pass it to these functions, but before that, you have to detect the item selection. You can do this by adding javascript code But again I won't suggest making this too much complex. So keep those two buttons as well as this.